# MS word for mac unable to select form field

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, macbook

I have a Word document that has form fields which I can't select or tick any of the check boxes. When trying to select it says "This command is not available because the document is locked for edit". I have tried to unprotect the document but because I never created it I will not have the password for it. Any Suggestions as to how I can select or choose these form fields?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, sorry. Once a file is user-protected, it's locked down.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and copy the entire document into a blank Word document and then edit it. In nearly every way the copied document will be the same as the original so hopefully this work around will suffice for you.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work for me.